# Microsoft Office Word 2007 Table of contents copy paste not perfect

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I copy pasted my graduation work from one word document to another to use different kind of template my university provided. Everything is good except two things inside table of contents. Program created wide spaces on some random places. Here is picture of it.

[image: http://aijaa.com/2s7M43]

I have problems with chapters 7.2.1, 7.2.2, 7.2.3, 7.2.4, 10 and 11. How could this be fixed, I´m frustrated about this cause everything else is ready now.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with the levels of your text, you can better fix this issue by going to:

**'VIEW'** tab > Select **'Outline'** on the left of ribbon (the **Views** group)

Now you'll **rounded minu** icon on the beginning of every line, this will help to fix your indentation issue. Just press **Tab** or **Shift+Tab** wherever your indentation of line isn't right.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! From outline view I figured out problem appeared whenever I added two numbers (like 10 or 43) and whenever I had three leves of headlines (7.1.1). So I guess problem is within template, can this be fixed though? Here is picture to demonstrate what I mean: http://aijaa.com/yGjUi5

Comment: You can fix this by going to **Home** tab then in the **Paragraph** group select **Multilevel List** icon then click **Define new Multilevel List** to fix your heading level issue.